# FileNotFoundException after packing in executable jar

Tags: plugins, jar, filenotfoundexception, maven-shade-plugin

After using maven shade plugin and running the executable jar, my application failed due to FileNotFoundException. During the application development I put my files in src/main/resources and so my path was defined like this "src/main/resources/maps/map.shp". Should I change all my paths in the code and how should I do that? Why does this happen?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ilija\Desktop
\MavenizedCP\cp-map\target\src\main\resources\maps\ParcelsCountyRDMFinal5.shp (T
he system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: What is the precise error message?

Comment: Use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` and use the path `/maps/ParcelsCountyRDMFinal5.shp`